# Using CURL in C++/C to issue a GET HTTP Request with a data file

Tags: c++, curl, get

Using the CURL at the command line:

curl -d @%1 -X GET https://blah-blah

This is in a Windows batch file and I pass the name of the file on the command line. Using this, I can issue a service call sending in a file with a whole lot of input parameters and I receive a substantial output.

For the life of me, when I try pro \grammatically, I can't make it work. It must be possible, since it can be done on the command. However, when I set

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
```

I can't upload a file, even if I set the callback

If I use:

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_Curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
```

the call becomes  'PUT', even though I try and force the header to be a GET. I follow the documentation and can see that this is the documented behavior. However, what is the pathway for avoiding this default?

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

Stan

Comment: You can't upload data in an HTTP `GET` request, only in a `PUT` or `POST` request.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it's not strictly forbidden but you shouldn't send a body with a GET request. On the other side a server should be able to handle a GET request with body but the response shouldn't be dependent of the content of the body.

If you really need to send a request containing a body with GET you can change the value of the method with `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`. This won't change the behavior of curl. This snippet will upload data with GET:

```
  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, port);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

    const auto* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, file);
    curl_easy_setopt(
        curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, static_cast<curl_off_t>(filesize));

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS command, to paste the body as a string. Afterwards you change the request to GET like in @Thomas Sablik s answer.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);

// Set target URL
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, requestURL.c_str());
// Set HTTP version
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, (long) CURL_HTTP_VERSION_3);
// Set POST fields
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, requestBody.c_str());
// Set request to get
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
// Set response target
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

// Perform CURL request
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```